RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 must have the same dtype, but got Long and Float
I am working on fine-tuning speecht5 tts model.Initially, i manually collected some elements for the dataset and started preprocessing them. After the preprocessing, i have saved them in '.npy' format. But i am facing the RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 must have the same dtype, but got Long and Float  for the below code:
import numpy as np
import torch
from transformers import SpeechT5ForTextToSpeech, SpeechT5Processor
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset

# Load processed audio data and transcripts
processed_audios = np.load('processed_audios.npy', allow_pickle=True)
transcripts = np.load('transcripts.npy', allow_pickle=True)

# Parameters
target_length = 16000  # Adjust according to your needs

# Function to preprocess audio data
def preprocess_audios(audios, target_length):
    processed = []
    for audio in audios:
        if len(audio) < target_length:
            padded_audio = np.pad(audio, (0, target_length - len(audio)), mode='constant')
            processed.append(padded_audio)
        else:
            processed.append(audio[:target_length])
    return np.array(processed)

# Preprocess audio clips
audio_tensors = preprocess_audios(processed_audios, target_length)
audio_tensors = torch.tensor(audio_tensors, dtype=torch.float32)

# Define the dataset class
class AudioTextDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, audio_tensors, transcripts):
        self.audio_tensors = audio_tensors
        self.transcripts = transcripts

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.transcripts)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return {
            'input_values': self.audio_tensors[idx],  # Audio tensor
            'text': str(self.transcripts[idx])          # Ensure transcript is a string
        }

# Create a dataset and DataLoader
dataset = AudioTextDataset(audio_tensors, transcripts)
data_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=8, shuffle=True)

# Load SpeechT5 model and processor
model_name = "microsoft/speecht5_tts"
processor = SpeechT5Processor.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = SpeechT5ForTextToSpeech.from_pretrained(model_name)

# Move model to GPU if available
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model.to(device)

# Define optimizer
optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=1e-4)

# Fine-tuning loop
num_epochs = 5
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()
    total_loss = 0
    for batch in data_loader:
        # Get the text input
        text_inputs = batch['text']

        # Ensure text_inputs are standard Python strings
        text_inputs = [str(text) for text in text_inputs]

        # Debugging: Print the contents of the batch
        print("Text inputs:", text_inputs)

        # Prepare text inputs for the processor
        text_inputs = processor(text=text_inputs, return_tensors='pt', padding=True, truncation=True).input_ids.to(device)

        # Forward pass (pass tokenized text as input, no audio)
        outputs = model(input_ids=text_inputs, labels=text_inputs)  # Use labels as text inputs
        loss = outputs.loss
        total_loss += loss.item()

        # Backward pass and optimization
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    avg_loss = total_loss / len(data_loader)
    print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}, Loss: {avg_loss:.4f}")

# Save the fine-tuned model
model.save_pretrained("fine_tuned_speacht5")
processor.save_pretrained("fine_tuned_speacht5")

print("Fine-tuning completed and model saved.")


Full set of output for the code:
Text inputs: ['TTS models are used for generating natural-sounding speech', 'RDS is a managed relational database service that simplifies database setup and scaling.', 'BGP is the protocol used to exchange routing information between different networks on the internet.', 'We implemented MFA to add an extra layer of protection to user accounts."', 'A higher area under the ROC curve indicates better classification performance.', 'We configured QoS to prioritize video conferencing traffic during remote meetings.', 'LSTMs are a type of RNN designed to capture long-term dependencies in sequential data.', 'RBAC restricts access to systems based on the roles assigned to users.']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\make.py", line 78, in <module>
    outputs = model(input_ids=text_inputs, labels=text_inputs)  # Use labels as text inputs
  File "C:\Users\nihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1736, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1747, in _call_impl  
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\speecht5\modeling_speecht5.py", line 2712, in forward
    outputs = self.speecht5(
  File "C:\Users\nihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1736, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1747, in _call_impl  
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\speecht5\modeling_speecht5.py", line 2210, in forward
    decoder_outputs = self.decoder(
  File "C:\Users\nihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1736, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1747, in _call_impl  
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\speecht5\modeling_speecht5.py", line 1731, in forward
    decoder_hidden_states = self.prenet(input_values, speaker_embeddings)
  File "C:\Users\nihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1736, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1747, in _call_impl  
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\speecht5\modeling_speecht5.py", line 690, in forward
    inputs_embeds = nn.functional.relu(layer(inputs_embeds))
  File "C:\Users\nihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1736, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1747, in _call_impl  
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nihaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\linear.py", line 125, in forward      
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 must have the same dtype, but got Long and Float


Please help me resolve this issue and get the resultant output.

Refer this link
